# Node.js error (could not find) while creating Hybrid app in visual studio 2013

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, hybrid-mobile-app

I have done fresh installation of Visual Studio 2013 - update 3 and have installed Visual studio 2013 MDA (Multi Device Application), and also have installed setup for Node js..

But when I create New Hybrid - Application project it shows me an error of "Node.js cannot be found"

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You need to have NodeJS installed on your system.

Get the installer from this page: http://nodejs.org/download/

After installation you should also check if `node` command is usable the command line (cmd).

If it's not available you will need to manually add NodeJS to your path.

Comment: Hi, thanks.. now I have done and now it is showing me error of "Error installing local npm package " and "getaddrinfo EAGAIN" while running the project..

Comment: Check if you have npm installed. Type `npm -v` in the command line. You should see the version or an error.

Comment: Yeah i have npm installed & its showing version but still i am getting an error.